# My Toolbar is not shown on API level 19 (Kitkat) while it is shown for API level 21

Tags: version-control, android-toolbar

My Code is not showing the Toolbar on Kitkat .
Here is my ScreenShot for both the version of Android.

Kitkat version:

[image: Kikat]

Lollipop version:

[image: Lollipop]

What might be the reason behind this.

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.global.market">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/image_front"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".detailactivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="6111000" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:clickable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:groupIndicator="@null">
    </ExpandableListView>

            <!--<ListView-->
                <!--android:background="@android:color/white"-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/menuList"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                if (toolbar != null) {
                    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                }
}
```

Build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    ext {
        supportLibVersion = '23.4.0'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.global.market"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'



}
```

Answer (score 8):

AppBar by default has elevation which works after lollipop. So it is always visible despite the layouts hierarchy. But on lower version (below lollipop) the toolbar might be drawn below some other layout.

So reorder your layout items to make the toolbar visible.

Comment: @Riyas Ahamed..Then where should i put my toolbar layout?

Comment: Wait a minute ..I will send the edited code to you in a minute.Dont consider the above code..There is something missing

Comment: The final code in 3 comments-
`
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:context="com.global.market.MainActivity">`

Comment: `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

Comment: That was a correct answer to my problem (similar to OP's problem).

Answer (score 0):

Change your `style.xml` to this

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and in `MainActivity.java` you are initiliaze two time `ToolBar` so remove second line this

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

you don't need it.

Comment: @Ironman-I have made the changes but It is not working still.

Comment: @samarthkejriwal in `styles.xml` you have two file like `styles.xml` and `styles.xml(v21)`. Can you post both file.

Comment: styles.xml(v21)
`<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
`

Comment: Still the same result..And the above changes is disturbing my other activity layout..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Update style.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name = "AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resource>
```

and also update the activity theme in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```