# Toolbar not showing in API Level 19 in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38454782/2139691) and I tried to reorder the views but the toolbar is still not visible on Android 19.

I don't know why the toolbar is not visible on android 19.

This is the [repo](https://github.com/rchampa/Android-Signature-App).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_picture"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_photo_white_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_pdf"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_picture_as_pdf_white_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_clear"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_delete_white_36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.example.ricardochampa.signatureapp.SignatureView
        android:id="@+id/signature_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/line_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your `SignatureView` has `layout_height=match_parent` and isn't constraint. So it will cover the whole screen including the toolbar.

Comment: But why this happens only on api<21?

Comment: Have a look at the comment from @Ben P in the answer. It states quite clearly. Elevation is a attribute that is only available on 21+ APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the layout below.

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_picture"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_photo_white_24dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_pdf"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_picture_as_pdf_white_24dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_clear"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_delete_white_36dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.example.ricardochampa.signatureapp.SignatureView
        android:id="@+id/signature_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/line_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in activity add (optionally)

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
```

The reason was `ToolBar` is getting hide by `SignatureView` . Although i donot have any idea right now how it is getting visible above 19.

Comment: On Lollipop+, elevation matters more than the order the views were declared in the layout. Since the toolbar has 4dp elevation, and everything else has none, on Lollipop+ you will be able to see it even though it was declared first in the layout.

Comment: Well i have never tested such scenario neither read about it  in anywhere in material design documentation. Thx for sharing . Can you point out the documentation for the same .

Comment: I cannot. That's not to say that it _isn't_ documented, but if it is, I don't know where. I just have my own personal experience to draw on. Though it should be noted that this makes logical sense if you think about the views as literally floating above the other views on the Z axis.